# Cakephp 3 how to use the TestSuite to test an update query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have the following action in my table file.

```
public function tokenChange($token){
        if(!$token) return false;
        return $this->query()
            ->update()
            ->set(['email_token' => NULL, 'email_verified'=>1, 'email_token_expires'=>NULL])
            ->where(['email_token' => $token])
            ->execute();
    }
```

This is the action in my TableTest

```
public function testTokenChange()
{
            $result = $this->Users->tokenChange('5404f27f3d9a4');
            $expected = TRUE;
            debug($result);
            $this->assertEquals($expected,$result);
}
```

I know the query doesn't return a boolean value. But how do I check to see if the update actually takes place without running another query to check the table??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would basically tests that the modified row was modified as you would expect:

```
public function testTokenChange()
{
    $id = $this->Users->findByEmailToken('5404f27f3d9a4')->first()->id;
    $this->Users->tokenChange('5404f27f3d9a4');
    $row = $this->Users->get($id);
    $expected = [
        'email_token' => null,
        'email_verified' => true,
        'email_token_expires' => null
    ];
    $this->assertEquals($expected, $row->extract(array_keys($expected)));
}
```